# Changing php.ini path on localhost

Tags: php, localhost

I have a localhost folder which mimics my server.
I just installed L-Ubuntu 13.04.
On my localhost folder, I don't know how to change which php.ini file gets loaded.

When i do phpinfo on my localhost, i get:
Loaded Configuration File:/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

How do I change that path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change path in httpd.conf setting

```
Configuration File     /usr/local/php5/lib/php.ini //example
```

[**Documentation**](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php)

Comment: you mean /etc/apache2.. nobe. no httpd.conf there. I just installed L-Ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: @hermanningjaldsson Under Ubuntu the Apache config file should be called apache2.conf

Comment: I added Configuration File path-to-my-ini but server crashed on restart. complained about that line. Instead i resorted to just copy my php.ini to that location the server is already pointing.

Comment: @john-jones this "solution" is really bad - you can have different php versions with different extensions installed

Comment: It's been 10 years i can't really remember those things anymore. If you have a better solution feel free to post it.